# OpenStreetMap labels - configuration

Tags: java, leaflet, vaadin, openstreetmap

The [OpenStreetMap](https://www.openstreetmap.org) map I'm using in the application shows the highway labels – those in pink squares below.

[image]

Is there a way to remove them so that they don't show on the map? They are of no use in the app and taking up too much space.

I'm using OpenStreetMap in Java via [Vaadin leaflet](https://vaadin.com/directory/component/v-leaflet).

TIA.

Comment: Does vaadin leaflet have any control over map rendering?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using raster [tiles](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tiles) you can't influence the map style since the rendering stylesheet is part of the tile server. However you can switch to a different tile server.

Comment: this is what I was expecting but not hoping. the standard as is seems to be the best. thx for response.